# The reason for dockerizing react application

Tags: reactjs, docker

I was learning react and came across such technology as docker and after some done research I just cannot get the benefit it brings for react apps, that is, most of the articles are about dockerizing backend such as Node.js and the one of benefits of docker for backend technologies is that if we want to scale our project in the future then we can take advantage of cloning backend project and put put load balancer in the front. I think it is what we want for our react app. So, pls can you briefly tell me the real benefits we get from dockerizing our reaect app.

Answer (score 0):

The general benefits of container technology will be available to your react app too. Chief among thrm is the extent of isolation a container provides to the config of your application. Apart from the bubble of security this isolation creates, it further  simplifies the system administration by making you able to define your Infrastructure as Code.

This ushers in the concept of GitOps to your DevOps which upholds the contemporary practices of hierarchical collaboration and shared responsibility of the up time of your system. Current software development schemes and large scale distributions depend highly on these principles.